# How to open a postgres database created using psql in PgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql

How do I open a postgres database created using psql (i.e. in the terminal) in PgAdmin4 and vice versa?

I also noticed that the localhost port for psql is `5432` and for PgAdmin4 is `5433`.

Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds like you have two different instances running on different ports the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background is in order. When you install Postgres you create an instance of a server that comes with three databases already created; template0, template1 and postgres. On a given machine you can create more then one  Postgres server/instance and have them run simultaneously. In order for that to happen though each server needs to listen on a different port. The default port is the `5432` you mention above. It would seem you also have another server running on port `5433`. I'm guessing what you want to know is about connecting to a given server rather then a database in that server. In that case it is important to know that Postgres works on the server/client model where it is the server and in your case `psql` and `pgAdmin` are the clients. What this means is that a Postgres server is not tied to a client, it exists on its own. It also means a client can connect to any Postgres server it can reach, assuming it is using the correct credentials. All of the previous means, yes you can connect `psql` and/or `pgAdmin` to either server. For `psql` specify the correct `port` using `-p`. For `pgAdmin` you will need to set up a server using the server dialog [Dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.27/server_dialog.html). Then use the appropriate `port` in the connection tab.